# MST and some facts via an example

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, trees

$M$ is an MST of the Weighted Graph - $GR$.

Let $A$ be a vertex of $GR$ then $M-${$A$} is also MST of $GR-${$A$}.

Let $A$  be a leaf of $M$ then $M-${$A$} is also MST of $GR-${$A$}.

If $e$ is a edge of $M$ then ($M-${$e$}) is a forest of $M1$ and $M2$ trees such that for $M_i, i=1,2$ is a MST of Induced Graph $GR$ on vertexes $T_i$.

My notes tell me that the **first** and **last** is false. I need some idea of how to understand the validity of these sentences in a more simple and concise manner.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65212172/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133001/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65102458/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3930612/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preamble

I'll use the following example to illustrate each statement. The graph below will be $GR$.

[image: gr]

Below is the MST $M$ of $GR$. These are the bolded edges.

[image: m]

### Statement One

The first statement is false if $A$ is an internal vertex of $M$. In that case, $M-\{A\}$ will result in a forest, which is not an MST.

Suppose we choose $A = d$, then $M-\{A\}$ will result in the following graph which is not a tree.

[image: m-a]

### Statement Two

The second statement is true. It is pretty easy to see why $M-\{A\}$ in this case is still an MST.

Suppose we choose $A = a$ (our only choices are $\{a,g,i\}$), then $M-\{A\}$ (left) will result in the following tree. We can compare it to $GR-\{A\}$ (right) and see that it is an MST.

[image: m-a gr-a]

### Statement Three

The third statement is true.

**Formal Proof of Statement Three**

Proof: Let $GR[T_1]$ and $GR[T_2]$ be induced subgraphs of $GR$ and $M_1'$ and $M_2'$ are their MSTs respectfully. Let $X$ be the set of edges that connect vertices of $T_1$ and $T_2$ in $GR$ (note $e \in X$).

To show $M_1$ and $M_2$ are MSTs, we must show is $M_1 = M_1'$ and $M_2 = M_2'$.

Let $w(M) = w(M_1) + w(e) + w(M_2)$ be the cost of the MST of $GR$.

Let $w(M_1')$ and $w(M_2')$ be the cost of the MST of $GR[T_1]$ and $GR[T_2]$.

Construct the graph $M' = M_1' \cup e \cup M_2'$. This graph is the MSTs of both induced graphs and a single edge that connects them. Note, we could use any edge from $X$, however for it to be a MST, we must select the minimum cost edge of $X$. So $w(M') = w(M_1') + w(e) + w(M_2')$.

Since $w(M_1')$, $w(e)$, and $w(M_2')$ are minimal, then $w(M')$ is minimal. Since $w(M')$ is minimal, then $w(M') = w(M)$. So,

\begin{align}
w(M_1') + w(e) + w(M_2') &= w(M') \\ &= w(M) \\ &= w(M_1) + w(e) + w(M_2). 
\end{align}

So $w(M_1') = w(M_1)$ and $w(M_2') = w(M_2)$, thus $M_1' = M_1$ and $M_2' = M_2$. Hence, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are MSTs.

**Intuition of Proof**

I'll pick $e = \{c,d\}$ to be the edge with weight one for this example. Below is $M-\{e\}$

[image: m-e]

Let $M_1$ be the tree on the left and $M_2$ be the tree on the right. Then $T_1 = \{a,b,c\}$ is the vertex set of $M_1$ and $T_2 = \{d,e,f,g,h,i\}$ is the vertex set of $M_2$. We need to construct the induced subgraphs of $GR$ on $T_1$ and $T_2$, $GR[T_1]$ and $GR[T_2]$. Below on the left is $GR[T_1]$, and below on the right is $GR[T_2]$.

[image: gr_t1 and gr_t2]

Now you can see the $M_1$ is the MST of $GR[T_1]$ (similarly for $M_2$).

In the proof, we abuse the fact that the MST of the induced subgraph and the original graph are minimal. We also use the fact that $M$ must contain $e$, the smallest edge that connects $M_1$ and $M_2$. We can conclude the only MST of the induced graphs is $M_1$ (for the left) and $M_2$ (for the right).

I hope this helps!

Comment: please clear comments.